# Add UiViewController to Root View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I add the sidebar to `self.viewcontroller` to init the content.
`self.viewController` is a rootViewController

```
- (void)setupViewControllers {
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [[BdbHomeListViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                   initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

    UIViewController *secondViewController = [[BdbExpiredListViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

    UIViewController *thirdViewController = [[BdbHistoryListViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *thirdNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                   initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];

    UIViewController *forthViewController = [[BdbChatRoomListViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *forthNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                   initWithRootViewController:forthViewController];

    UIViewController *fithViewController = [[RightViewController alloc]init];
    UIViewController *fithNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                   initWithRootViewController:fithViewController];

    RDVTabBarController *tabBarController = [[RDVTabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController,
                                           thirdNavigationController,forthNavigationController,fithNavigationController]];

    TheSidebarController *sidebar = [[TheSidebarController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.viewController rightSidebarViewController:fithNavigationController];
    self.viewController = tabBarController;

    [self customizeTabBarForController:tabBarController];
}
```

Comment: Did you try `self.window.rootViewController= self.viewController;` ?

Comment: [self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
this already set, just i refer some library, the sidebar have to at rootviewcontroller also, i duno what should i do

Comment: Ok and finally `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` ?

Comment: yup, Got, can u email me at karheng5321@gmail ? i need help seriously

Comment: Ok so the problem is that you need to set `self.window.rootViewController= sidebar`

Comment: self.viewController already is a rootviewcontroller .
now i want to put 
`self.viewController = tabBarController;`
`self.viewController = sidebar;`
at the same time
how

Comment: I can't understand the problem. Why would you want to do that at the same time? Can you show me the UI?

Comment: Sorry I don't do private consultation. Please post your problem here if possible so other people can also help you.

Comment: Is this method -setupViewControllers implementation code (that you have posted) reside in a ViewController class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do:

```
TheSidebarController *sidebar = [[TheSidebarController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tabBarController rightSidebarViewController:fithNavigationController];
self.window.rootViewController= sidebar;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Also you don't need this:

```
self.viewController = tabBarController;
```

Comment: then my `tabBarController` how to rootview

Comment: You cannot set your tabBarController as the root view because side bar will never be shown if you do that. Your tabBarController will be the content view for the side bar

Comment: Ya, tat the problem, how i set both tabbar and sidebar is rootview at the same time

Comment: T_T any idea or solution >.< i doing a tabbar with can side the menu
like Airbnb ios app

Comment: Yes the solution provided above will do just that. Did you try using the answer I posted?